# Codeigniter: Not inserting data in table

Tags: codeigniter

## Update: It is solved ..

For some reason, the data is not getting inserted into the table. It is however being posted from the form as I could see with var dump, but further than that, won't do. So, here are the 3 modules. It is a very simple test scheme: Just a form with two fields, you press Submit and should be inserted. (I can do all that in ordinary PHP with one page, but, the MVC frameworks are a nightmare in this regard, you write about 30 times more code than you would need in procedural.

```
<?php

class Inserting_controller extends CI_Controller {

     public function __construct()
       {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('Inserting_model');

       }


     public function index ()
     {

        $this->load->view('inserting_view'); 
     }

    // Controller
     public function insert()
     {
     $data = array(
        'username' => $this->input->post('username', TRUE),
        'password' => sha1($this->input->post('password', TRUE)
     ));


     var_dump($data); // We do get the data posted
      exit;

     $this->Inserting_model->insertdata($data); // this should forward them to the Model
}
}
?>

==============
MODEL

    <?php


    class Inserting_model extends CI_Model{


        function __construct()
        {
            // Call the Model constructor
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->database();
        }


            public function insertdata($data)
                {
                 $this->db->insert('users', $data);
                } 


    }

    ?>

========
VIEW



    <div id="inserting_form">

            <?php echo form_open('index.php/Inserting_controller/insert/'); ?> 

          <ul>

                <li>



                <label>Username</label>      

                <div><?php echo form_input(array('id' => 'username', 'name' => 'username')); ?></div>

               </li>
               <li>
                <label>Password</label>      

                <div><?php echo form_password(array('id' => 'password', 'name' => 'password')); ?></div>   
                </li>   

                <li><?php echo validation_errors();?></li>

                <li><?php echo form_submit(array('name' =>'submit'),'Insert');?> </li>

          </ul>

          <?php echo form_close(); ?>

            </div>
```

Comment: It's a nightmare for beginners and a nightmare only for a while, when you don't have to reuse any of your code.

Comment: Thank you, good to know.! I do see that there are multiple useful classes built in that care for security, validation etc and I appreciate that, but because of that extra work I was on the brink of quitting. If you tell me that it is going to be worth, I ll stick to it, thanks

Comment: It is worth even without extra classes, you will see all the benefits as you well get used to CI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blushing :/

On writing the debugging code, I forgot to delete the exit; thus, the program exited right after that ....